# How can we run Cypress tests in parallel on a single machine?

Tags: jenkins, cypress, parallel-testing, parallel-tests

I need to run my tests on a single machine. The project has more than 50 tests (spec files).

Is it possible to achieve this via Jenkins configuration?

Comment: Cypress docs doesn't recommend running the tests in parallel on a single machine because you might run into resource issues on that machine. But there are options to run them in local. Refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423529/is-there-any-way-to-run-parallel-cypress-tests-on-local-machine-for-example-5-s

Answer (score -2):

You could run parallel tests in docker containers and use sorry-cypress.

https://sorry-cypress.dev/

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31935236)